# PHP/ Magento - Convert date format

Tags: php, magento

This is on a magento RMA email template, Im trying to convert the date format from US to UK. I’ve tried the below but nothing renders out on the frontend - does anyone know where I am going wrong please?

```
<?php 
    $originalDate = "{{var rma.getDateForCollection()}}";
    $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
    echo $newDate;
?>
```

Comment: You put in `strtotime` wrong value.

Comment: Whats wrong with it?

Comment: You think string "{{var rma.getDateForCollection()}}" is evaluating to variable which hold time, but it doesn`t.